# Redux reselect for object have string as key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, reselect

I have trouble get access for the object like below in reselect, hope someone had some idea can help me out.

```
const data = state => fruit.selectors.data(state);

This will return an object like this:

{
  "10.Kroger": {
    "fruit": "Banana",
    "price": "10",
    "store": "Kroger",
  },
   "5.Heb": {
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "price": "5",
    "store": "Heb",
  },
   "12.Wallmart": {
    "fruit": "Pineapple",
    "price": "12",
    "store": "wallmart",
  },
}
```

And here's my createSelector

```
export const getFruitData = createSelector(
  data,
  (state, price, store) => price,
  (state, price, store) => store,
  (data, price, store) => data[`${price}.${store}`]
);
```

I tried to get dynamic result by the value pass in:

`data["10.Kroger"]`
should get back this object as an result:

```
 {
    "fruit": "Banana",
    "price": "10",
    "store": "Kroger",
 },
```

Is possible to make this work in reselect? 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't seem to benefit from any memoization layer. You might consider leaving `reselect` out and write a plain selector function, roughly like this:

```js
const data = state => fruit.selectors.data(state);

export function getFruitData(state, price, store) {
  const itemData = data(state);
  return itemData[`${price}.${store}`]
};
```